# Why does it show an error when I try to save a pandas DataFrame file into an arff using arff.dump()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, arff

I'm trying to save a data file into arff using the python module arff
(!pip install arff)

```
    import arff
arff.dump('test.arff',(test_data.values),relation='test',names=test_data.columns)
```

Where test_data.values is:

```
array([[1.1328568635167084, 0, Interval(104.325, 172.5, closed='right'),
    ..., 1.6058143807097698, 1.3952829499479982, 'N'],
   [0.15793794555170337, 0, Interval(104.325, 172.5, closed='right'),
    ..., -0.6085702987974523, -0.2235535554899603, 'N'],
   [-2.035629619869558, 1, Interval(104.325, 172.5, closed='right'),
    ..., 0.9466831550370516, -0.5754745349329947, 'O'],
   ...,
   [-0.6341836752948632, 0, Interval(104.325, 172.5, closed='right'),
    ..., -1.4454447763369709, -0.55923202818947, 'N'],
   [1.559383890126398, 1, Interval(104.325, 172.5, closed='right'),
    ..., 0.09499673984196622, 0.9134219165567661, 'N'],
   [1.1937892958895213, 1, Interval(104.325, 172.5, closed='right'),
    ..., -1.9638625942818055, -1.338872351878654, 'N']], dtype=object)
```

However when I run this, I get the following error.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-309-26bed33f7414> in <module>()
----> 1 arff.dump('test.arff',(test_data.values),relation='test',names=data.columns)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/arff/__init__.py in generate_lines(self, row)
    337                 item_type = type(item)
    338                 if item_type not in self.pytypes:
--> 339                     raise ValueError("Unknown type: %s" % item_type)
    340                 ftypes.append(self.pytypes[item_type])
    341             if self.names is None:

ValueError: Unknown type: <class 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'>
```

Note that I had done binning (pd.cut and pd.qcut) on two of the attributes (attr3 and attr4).

Is there any way to fix this error?

Thanks.